# How to Add a product to the cart and then update the quantity from both the product page and from the cart itself.

Tags: angularjs

I am completely stumped on how to achieve something specific that the below website has achieved. Does anyone know how to update the quantity of a product from the product details page to the shopping cart, and have that quantity shared/bound between the cart and and the product details page for each an every product repeated from a collection. (I am not talking about simply having a global cart quantity total via a simple custom directive). Please see the link below. Add a product to the cart and then update the quantity from both the product page and from the cart itself. This is what I am trying to achieve. Thank you all in advance!

http://demo.shopnx.in/

Comment: Word of advice...you need to show some code that you've written in order to get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'll get better responses if you post some code that you have tried and then ask to be guided on where you are going wrong. I've created a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zk9vujo/) to demonstrate one method of doing this. It is extremely simple, contrived, not production worthy by any stretch of the imagination and doesn't really do much, but it should show you one construct that will allow you to accomplish the functionality you're after.

The key is to use some type of shared storage so that the same array of items is available to both your product listing and the cart. In the sample I have done this using a Value:

```
.value('cartStorage', {
    items: []
})
```

This value is then injected in the main controller:

```
.controller('mainController', function(cartStorage) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.cartStorage = cartStorage;

    _this.items = [{
        name: 'Apple',
        price: .5,
        quantity: 0,
        showAddToCart: false,
        addedToCart: false
    }, {
        name: 'Orange',
        price: .5,
        quantity: 0,
        showAddToCart: false,
        addedToCart: false
    }, {
        name: 'Grapes',
        price: 1,
        quantity: 0,
        showAddToCart: false,
        addedToCart: false
    }];

    _this.addToCart = function(item) {
        _this.cartStorage.items.push(item);
        item.addedToCart = true;
    }

    _this.increaseItemAmount = function(item) {
        item.quantity++;
        item.showAddToCart = true;
    }

    _this.decreaseItemAmount = function(item) {
        item.quantity--;
        if (item.quantity <= 0) {
            item.quantity = 0;
            item.addedToCart = false;
            item.showAddToCart = false;
            var itemIndex = _this.cartStorage.items.indexOf(item);
            if (itemIndex > -1) {
                _this.cartStorage.items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
            }
        } else {
            item.showAddToCart = true;
        }
    }
})
```

As well as the cart controller:

```
.controller('cartController', function(cartStorage) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.cartStorage = cartStorage;

    _this.increaseItemAmount = function(item) {
        item.quantity++;
    }

    _this.decreaseItemAmount = function(item) {
        item.quantity--;
        if (item.quantity <= 0) {
            item.quantity = 0;
            item.addedToCart = false;
            item.showAddToCart = false;
            var itemIndex = _this.cartStorage.items.indexOf(item);
            if (itemIndex > -1) {
                _this.cartStorage.items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    _this.removeFromCart = function(item) {
        item.quantity = 0;
        item.addedToCart = false;
        item.showAddToCart = false;
        var itemIndex = _this.cartStorage.items.indexOf(item);
        if (itemIndex > -1) {
            _this.cartStorage.items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        }
    }
})
```

Now the `cartStorage` object is shared so any update made in one controller will automagically be reflected in the other controller. All that's left is the markup:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainController as main">
        <h2>Main Controller</h2>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in main.items">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.price | currency}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="main.increaseItemAmount(item)">+</button>
                        <button ng-click="main.decreaseItemAmount(item)">-</button>
                        <button ng-click="main.addToCart(item)" ng-show="item.showAddToCart && !item.addedToCart">Add to Cart</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="cartController as cart">
        <h2>Cart Controller</h2>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in cart.cartStorage.items">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.price | currency}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="cart.increaseItemAmount(item)">+</button>
                        <button ng-click="cart.decreaseItemAmount(item)">-</button>
                        <button ng-click="cart.removeFromCart(item)">Remove from Cart</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update showing the usage of a Factory instead of Value**

Instead of using a Value use this service:

```
.factory('cartStorage', function() {
    var _cart = {
        items: []
    };
    var service = {
        get cart() {
            return _cart;
        }
    }
    return service;
})
```

Then modify the code in the controllers to use the `.cart` property of the service instead of the value. You only need to change one line of code in both controllers. Change:

```
_this.cartStorage = cartStorage;
```

to:

```
_this.cartStorage = cartStorage.cart;
```

[Here is an updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zk9vujo/1/).

Comment: Thank you so much Lex! Your answer is brilliant and one of the most top notch/complete I have probably ever received over SO. I truly appreciate all the time and effort you put into this as I am sure anyone else reading this will as well! I am going through all of it right now. Thanks again.

Comment: Lex, how would you refactor this if you were to use the factory service recipe instead of a value service recipe? Thanks again.

Comment: @user791134 I have updated the answer to show the use of a factory.

Comment: I am having issues maintaining the state of the item quantity selected in the Main Controller View, after returning from the Cart Controller View. Is there something that needs to be added with regards to UI-router in order to maintain state in the Main Controller View? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. The items array is maintained in the value (or factory if you have gone that route). It might be best to start a new question showing your current code base and explaining the issue you're facing in greater detail.

Comment: Created a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760497/persisting-state-between-different-views-using-ui-router

Answer (score 1):

I made [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/amyNRTSqDe5qpxyBpUXK) as an example.

I've used events to achieve the desired behavior. (
This is just one way of doing this, should have a lot of possibilities)

ProductsController:

```
app.controller('ProductsCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.products = [
        {
            'name': 'Product One',
            'price': 10,
            'qty': 0
        },
        {
            'name': 'Product two',
            'price': 20,
            'qty': 0
        }
    ];

    // Fire event to add
    $scope.add = function(product) {
        product.qty++;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('addProduct', product.price);
    }

    // Fire event to remove
    $scope.remove = function(product) {
        if(product.qty > 0) {
            product.qty--;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('removeProduct', product.price);
        }
    }
});
```

CartController:

```
app.controller('CartCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.total = 0;

    // Catch the event to add
    $scope.$on('addProduct', function(event, data) {
       $scope.total += data;
    });

    // Catch the event to remove
    $scope.$on('removeProduct', function(event, data) {
        $scope.total -= data;   
    });
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="CartCtrl">Total: {{total}}</div>
<br>
<div ng-controller="ProductsCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <span>Name: {{product.name}}</span>
        <br>
        <span>Price:{{product.price}}</span>
        <span>Quantity:{{product.qty}}</span>
        <br>
        <button type="button" ng-click="add(product);">Add</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="remove(product);">Remove</button>
        <br><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help Gabriel, but what Lex's answer showed is what I am trying to achieve. Thank you regardless. It was very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a shared service between your Product details and Cart detail controller which can have an array where you can push the the Product selected with its quantity and other details.